# File Upload in Documentum through ajax

Tags: java, jquery, documentum6.5

Is there any way we can upload files to Content server either in TaskSpace 6.6 or Web Publisher 6.5 through ajax.Current I am using execute method of ActionService class which unfortunately refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery uploadify

Documentation and downloads available at

> http://www.uploadify.com/